# I tried downloading elementaryos 3 times but is it ever so slow

Tags: download

I paid twice for the download but I am having so many problems with the slowest download I ever experienced.  How about 14kb/sec.  At this rate, it can take over a day to complete it, if it completes it.  It hung up on me twice and had to start all over again.  Due to the slowness, I can see where it would hang up.  If I can use Torrent, how do I go about to do that?  If all else fails, how can I order a flash drive with the os on it?  That would solve my problem.  Where I live doesn't help either.  I am off the beaten path relying on the slowest internet provider and there is nothing I can do.  If you can please help me with this and like I said earlier, I would be happy to get a flash or USB drive with the os on it.  Thank you very much.

Mel

Answer (score 2):

When you click "Download elementary OS" button on the download page, there is a magnet icon near the download button. Click on that icon to get the torrent magnet link and use your a torrent downloader like [uTorrent](https://www.utorrent.com/) to download it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  No, I did not know that was Torrent Magnet.  I just checked my download and it is still coming along.  Maybe, in a few hours it will be done.  I am wondering if I can do the iso on DVD with the built in program on win 10?  I just checked the download again and it shows it was interrupted.  Now, I would have to start all over again but this time I will do the Torrent.

Comment: The preferred installation would be from a USB drive and using Rufus to create the USB drive within Windows. However, burning the image to a DVD may work as well. If going the route of using a DVD I believe you will want to used the slowest speed setting when writing to the DVD.